# How can I create a new row in an HTML table

Tags: javascript, html, html-table

I am trying to add a new row to this little table with just one column. Can anybody help? I created a new function for this purpose, for the moment it is not working.

[image]

```js
function row_creator() {
  var table = document.getElementById("myTable")[0];
  var newRow = table.insertRow();
  var newCell = newRow.insertCell(0);
  var newText = document.createTextNode('New row');
  newCell.appendChild(newText);
}
row_creator();
```

```css
table,
th,
td {
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<! --COMIENZO TABLA -->

<table id="MyTable" class="egt">



  <! --PRIMERA LINEA -->

  <tr>
    <th>Source ID</th>
  </tr>

  <! --SEGUNDA LINEA -->

  <tr>
    <td>
      <input type="number" id="fname" name="fname">
    </td>
    <tr>

</table>
```

Answer (score 2):

There are errors in this line `document.getElementById("myTable")[0]`

1. `getElementById` returns a element (not a collection) so no need of `[0]`
2. The Id must match your element Id `MyTable` with capital **M**

Answer (score 1):

```js
function row_creator() {
  var table = document.getElementById("mytable"); /*not nedd [0] & same name use fore html and js*/
  var newRow = table.insertRow(); /* nedd position of row */
  var newCell = newRow.insertCell();/* add col in table*/
  newCell.innerHTML = "NEW CELL1"; /* to insert data in row [newCell] is var we have define and innerHTML to add html data*/ 
}


setInterval(row_creator, 1000);/* setInterval(className, Time[1000 = 1s]); */
```

```css
table,
th,
td {
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<table id="mytable" class="egt">
    <! --PRIMERA LINEA -->
    <tr>
        <th>Source ID</th>
    </tr>
    <! --SEGUNDA LINEA -->
    <tr>
        <td>
            <input type="number" id="fname" name="fname">
        </td>
        <tr>
</table>
```

Comment: I would like to do it atomatically without any button

Comment: setInterval(addnew, 1000);

Comment: tip :- setInterval(loaddata, 5000); in (1000 = 1s)

Comment: Run again......

Comment: Explaining what you changed in the code and why makes for much more upvote-worthy answers...

Comment: var table = get table;  ----  var newRow = table.insertRow(0) [ create new row in this table] -------   var newCell = newRow.insertCell(0)[ this new row add new col(<td>)]  ------- newCell.innerHTML = "NEW CELL1" [to put value (your data to add HTML value)]

Comment: This is your code try it